# Go http POST file

Tags: http, go

I'm really new in Go and I have to integrate [Zamzar](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs) in a Go microservice. I need to `POST` a file and a data type (string).

Doing a `curl` looks like this:

`curl https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs \
 -u user:pass \
 -X POST \
 -F "source_file=@/tmp/portrait.gif" \
 -F "target_format=png"`

This is what I have so far:

```
client := &http.Client{}

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs", nil)

req.SetBasicAuth("user", "pass")

resp, err := client.Do(req)

if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("Error : %s", err)
} else {
  fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

How can I send the `target_format` as a string and `source_file` as a file? **I already have the file (`[]byte`)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [multipart.Writer](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#Writer) to create the request body:

```
 var buf bytes.Buffer
 mpw := multipart.NewWriter(&buf)
 w, err := mpw.CreateFormFile("source_file", "portrait.gif")
 if err != nil {
    // handle error
 }
 if _, err := w.Write(imageBytes); err != nil {
    // handle error
 }
 if err := mpw.WriteField("target_format", "png"); err != nil {
   // handle error
 }
 if err := mpw.Close(); err != nil {
    // handle error
 }

 req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs", &buf)
 req.Header.Set("Content-Type", mpw.FormDataContentType())

 ... continue as before.
```